# Json VS SQLite which is more suitable for Android/iOS development

Tags: android, ios, json, sqlite

We developing an app that will store data locally on phone, on server and share it between users. The access to store and retrieve data will be approximately 20 times a day for each user, it will consist mostly of strings. The app will be cross platform Android/iOS. So before beginning developing DB what you suggest Json vs SQlite or use HTTP Methods: GET, POST.
What are advantages and disadvantages of each, and what do you suggest.

Comment: You will need all of those: Using a GET request for fetching JSON data and then storing those objects persistently in a SQLite database. Note that JSON is not a DB; and asking _"Json vs Sqlite or use HTTP Methods: GET, POST"_  doesn't make much sense at all: those are orthogonal concepts which cannot be replaced by each other. You may however, use XML instead of JSON, or some other persistent store than SQLite, or use some custom protocol over TCP instead of HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not agree that sql is slow.  It's not like these devices are using spinning disks.  In my app, i've implemented a RESTful API that passes JSON data back.  This is easy because on iOS, json can be easily converted to the iOS Native NSDictionary object.

I recommend storing data using sqlite or Core Data because you'll be happy for it later on if you need to query the data.  That's what databases are used for, storing and retrieving data easily.

As an alternative, you can also consider building the SQLite database on the server, and actually downloading that file to the devices.  This has it's benefits because you won't need to do the actual sqlite processing on device.

I recommend staying away from XML, not because it's bad, but because passing JSON data back has become standard, and a lot of large companies are moving away from XML formats because of the processing power required.

In designing your RESTful API, it's always good practice to use the already available HTTP request methods.  Use GET to retrieve data, POST to create new data, PUT to update data and DELETE to remove data.  Once you have a beautifully designed REST api, all things things should just fall into place and you'll have an app that's maintainable and scalable on the client and on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This question really depends on your own area of expertise. If you have good understanding of JSON, then use that. XML is another great way via SOAP (or REST) to distribute data to your platforms, Server -> Device -> Server. My own experience is that JSON with GZIP is small and fast and there exists lots of parsers that is fast. XML has the downside that it gets big quickly but is often easier to maintain over time since the syntax is set in the "namespace" of your XML. SQLite is slow, since its disk based and should only be used for persistent storage of data. Access it as little as possible during runtime. My suggestion: JSON+GZIP, REST-api on server/device, store as much as possible in memory on devices, SQLite for persistent storage on devices and lastly MySQL on server for persistent storage (free, fast enough if done correctly with views and methods).

But as said, this is all up to the implementation.